What is the physical significance of $d_{x^2-y^2}$ or $d_{z^2}$ contributing in $t_{2g}$ levels?
In crystal field theory, we know that when a transition metal is surrounded by ligands (let octahedral symmetry), five fold degeneracy of $d$ orbitals lift up and split into triply degenrate $t_{2g}$ levels which contains $d_{xy}$, $d_{yz}$, $d_{xz}$ orbitals and in doubly degenrate $e_g$ levels with $d_{x^2-y^2}$ and $d_{z}^2$ orbitals. But recently I found this paper where I have seen that $d_{x^2-y^2}$ is contributing in $t_{2g}$ section. So what is the physical significance behind this ?
